# How to kill JS object with attached keymaster.js listeners

Tags: javascript, zombie-process

I'm having an issue where I have a phantom `game` object floating around in my JavaScript program that's still attached to my keyboard input handler (keymaster.js).

In the code below, I run `startGame` in  demo mode when the page first loads, in order to display a simulated game while the user is reading the splash screen.

Then when the user presses the "Start" button, I rerun `startGame`.  However, at this point, whenever the user presses a keystroke, two bullets are fired instead of one.  I've discovered that there are two separate 'game' objects responding to the keystrokes, and each is firing a bullet.

How can I completely reset my game state between games and kill all associated objects in memory?

```
var startGame = function(demoMode) {
    this.game = new TypingFrenzy.Game({
        "ctx": ctx,
        "ctx_kbd": ctx_kbd,
        "demoMode": demoMode
    });

    this.currentGameView = new TypingFrenzy.GameView(this.game, ctx);
    this.currentGameView.start();
}

startGame(true)
```

Below is the code where I bind my event handlers, in response to meager's comment:

```
GameView.prototype.bindKeyHandlers = function () {
 var ship = this.ship;

 for (i = 33; i <= 64; i++) {
  var chr = String.fromCharCode(i);
  key(chr, function (event, handler) { ship.processKeystroke(event, handler)   });
}
};
```

Unbinding my key listeners from my `game` object allowed my `game` object to be deleted.  I used the following command:

```
key.unbind('a');
```

Thanks meager!

Comment: You can't, based on what you've posted. You need to show us where you bind your event handlers, because those calls need to be balanced with unbinding calls.

Comment: after reading the keymaster.js documentation, I think my answer will be: `key.unbind('a');`  I will test this.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.  See my edits to the original question.

```
key.unbind('a');
```